# Get blob storage content in powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm using Get-AzureStorageBlobContent command to get the blob which holds version of my app:

```
$latestDeployment = (Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob app.version -Container container -Context $blobContext)
```

This command saves it as a file to the disk, while I would like to load it to memory and just read the content without saving anything. Is it possible using powershell?

Comment: I thought this was a decent question, why the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, it is not possible for you to do it by using Power Shell. With Power Shell, you could list, download, copy blobs, but you could not directly read blobs in storage account. If you want to read blobs, you need download them locally and read them. More information about how to manage blobs with Power Shell please refer to this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/wiki/Microsoft-Azure-Storage-Cmdlets).

However, it is easy for you to use codes to read blobs in storage account. Please refer to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020158/reading-line-by-line-from-blob-storage-in-windows-azure).

Answer (score 11):

This should work

```
$latestDeploymentBlob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob app.version -Container $container -Context $blobContext 
$latestDeployment = $latestDeploymentBlob.ICloudBlob.DownloadText()
```

Comment: Thanks @x5657  this worked for me. Not sure why this is missing from the azure docs.

Comment: Perfect, and totally not obvious :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$latestDeployment = Get-Content (Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob app.version -Container container -Context $blobContext)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: The Get-AzureStorageBlob returns an AzureStorageBlob object, and Get-Content can't infer the path from this. Thus, running Get-Content on this object errors out with a "Can not find path" message.